# Axios POST request receiving ERROR on Desktop App But Same URL Works In Browser

Tags: javascript, post, web-scraping, axios, cgi

I am building an application that scrapes and aggregates a lot of real estate data from various sites.

I am having an issue with one of the sites. I send an Axios `POST` request with the required `form` data.

When I take that exact `url` string and enter it in the browser, I am brought to the desired page. However, using the exact same data from my own server returns this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd" >
<html>
<head>
<title>Search Results</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
</head>

<form method=post>
<body bgcolor=WHITE text=BLACK link=GOLDENROD vlink=RED 
      alink=RED>
<input type=hidden name=POSTDATA value='{"ms_user":"monm","passwd":"data","srch_type":"1","select_cc":"0701","district":"0714","adv":"1","out_type":"2","ms_ln":"50","p_loc":"143-145+Chadwick+Ave","owner":"","block":"","lot":"","qual":""}' >
<input type=hidden name=pageno value='1' >
ERROR
```

I have tried sending the `POST` request with the entire query string as it would be in the browser. This is what that would be: `https://tax1.co.monmouth.nj.us/cgi-bin/inf.cgi?ms_user=monm&passwd=data&srch_type=1&select_cc=0701&district=0714&adv=1&out_type=2&ms_ln=50&p_loc=141-143+Chadwick+Ave&owner=&block=&lot=&qual=`

I have also tried sending the `POST` with the `data object` like so:

```
let asessmentURL = `https://tax1.co.monmouth.nj.us/cgi-bin/inf.cgi?`

        //First we grab the body of the html with axios
        const response = await axios.post(asessmentURL, {
            'ms_user': 'monm', 
            'passwd': 'data',
            'srch_type': '1',
            'select_cc': '0701', 
            'district': '0714',
            'adv': '1',
            'out_type': '2',
            'ms_ln': '50',
            'p_loc': '143-145+Chadwick+Ave',
            'owner': '',
            'block': '',
            'lot': '',
            'qual': ''
        }, { headers: { 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0' } 
        })
        .then(response => console.log("RESPONSE: ", response.data))
```

I have also tried using POSTMAN to send the request and it returns the same `HTML` and `ERROR` as the application on my server.

Any ideas? Please and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it! There were two pitfalls that I would like to mention in the event someone goes down this path one day.

Although the DEV Tools on Chrome AND the form `method="post"` said the request was a `POST` request, I produced the desired results using a `GET` request. After doing some research I saw that `CGI` form submissions need to be `GET` requests.

After incorporating that, I was no longer receiving the same error. Now I was getting a "property not found" error. I noticed that the address was being passed with `+` instead of spaces. I added the `%20` for proper spacing and voila!!!